# MySql, CONCAT and NOT IN, string values

Tags: mysql, concatenation, notin

I have such query but it doesn't select anything, but it should. So query

```
SELECT * 
FROM _custom_access_call 
WHERE CONCAT(type, name) NOT IN ('string1', 'string2', 'string3')
```

I manually add to table entry with null and '1sfgsg' values but it wasn't selected. Why? I need to select all entries that concat values is not in array. Help to deal with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one of the values is `NULL`, then `CONCAT()` will return `NULL`. And `NULL NOT IN (...)` is always `NULL`. Also `NULL IN (...)` is always `NULL`. If you want to use `NULL` you should explicitally handle it. In this specific case, `CONCAT_WS()` helps, because it never returns `NULL`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM _custom_access_call 
WHERE CONCAT_WS('', type, name) NOT IN ('string1', 'string2', 'string3');
```

Also, note that this query cannot use any index.